# How to correctly invoke awk in Perl to print out the 3rd last field in a line?

Tags: perl, awk

My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $line="1 2 3 4 5 6 7";
print $line;
my $thirdlast=`print $line |awk '{print $(NF-3)}'`;
print $thirdlast;
```

The output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7   awk: 0602-542 There is an extra ) character.
 The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                {print 201 1 >>>  201NF-3) <<< 
 Syntax Error The source line is 1.
 awk: 0602-502 The statement cannot be correctly parsed. The source line is 1.
        awk: 0602-542 There is an extra ) character.
```

What is it complaining about? Anything wrong with my script? Couldn't understand why it says `The source line is 1`.

What fix is needed by my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to call `awk` inside your `perl` program, `perl` provides the necessary functions to perform such operation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $line="1 2 3 4 5 6 7";
my @tab = split(/\s+/, $line);
print $tab[-3],"\n";
```

This small program outputs: `5`

Comment: My real input is something like `Location3 Media                    40        n l3m`. In this case, the output is null. Guess I need something like `split(/\s/, $line)`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks a lot, Sylvain. Fool me, forgot the `+` after `\s`. Blushed...

Answer (score 5):

A Sylvain pointed out, you really don't need to call `awk` from within `perl` since the latter can do anything the former can. However, to answer your original question, you need to i) escape the `$` inside the `awk`, ii) correctly pass your Perl variable to the subshell you launch (`print` is something completely different in the shell). Something like:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $line="1 2 3 4 5 6 7";
## Use echo, not print and escape the $ in $(NF-3)
my $thirdlast=`echo "$line" |awk '{print \$(NF-3)}'`;
print $thirdlast;
```

Answer (score 1):

The same thing can be done with `cut` like so:

```
cut -d ' ' -F <field>
```